# how to check if string in column matches another column, regardless of row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two columns to see if strings in one column exist in another even if the row numbers don't match.

The columns look like this:

```
A              B
```

```
Classic        Classic
Classic Rock   Rock
Kpop           Pop
Jpop           Hip-Hop
Rock           Classic Rock
Jazz           Jazz
```

I want to be able to create a new table with B that looks like the following:

```
B              C
```

```
Classic        True
Rock           True
Pop            False
Hip-Hop        False
Classic Rock   True
Jazz           True
```

I tried using

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)
```

But this only provided whether the strings in the row matched, and I'm looking for a way so that row placement does not matter.

Comment: `df.B.isin(df.A)`

Comment: Here's a post on how to do a [Cartesian Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426843/cartesian-product-of-a-pandas-dataframe-with-itself) for pandas DataFrames.

Comment: Use a free variable `row` to iterate through column A; apply `any`, such as `any(df.B == row.A)`.  Is that enough of a hint?

Comment: Thanks guys! `isin` did it :)